# Recommended Tools and macros for Dark Heresy in Roll 20

Tags: tools, dark-heresy-1e, tokens

Our group is currently meeting for a Dark Heresy campaign on **Roll20**. We have found some interesting tokens, built a few macros and the character sheets and we are learning more about the internal tools.
However I would like to know if there are any further helps already made that we could use for Dark Heresy and all WH40K rpgs. I've googled around but I'm not sure I'm reaching all content out there, since here I see many more players employing virtual tables for these games. So I think that we are mostly looking for the following.

1. Websites and libraries with these (like **darkreign.org**)
2. Handouts
3. Tokens and token making tools (like **TokenTool**).
4. Maps, local and starmaps tools
5. Anything else (music, macros and so on)

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [about] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. This question is *really* broad, with a TON of answers that would all be equally likely to help you, and Stack Exchange is designed to handle more specific questions. I don't know Warhammer well enough to help you narrow things down, but generally the thing to do is talk more about your specific situation, challenges, needs, and concerns.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually did look at the rules before hand and I thought that it fitted with the the "On Topic" section where it actually says that a possible topic is **Tools and equipment used while playing table-top RPGs (including running them online);**

Comment: Oh, it's not off-topic, the general theme is great! We just need to narrow it down a little. Right now you're asking for any resources that can help in running an online game; if we can get it to be about resources for running *your* online game, the answers will be more useful and less just random guessing until someone hits on what you're after. Until then, the question's on hold to avoid filling up with answers that turn out to be irrelevant to your needs.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to think for a bit on how to make it more explicit.

Comment: [Music selection](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/how-do-i-select-background-music-for-my-fantasy-rpg-campaign) has been dealt with in another question already, so you can probably eliminate that to quickly narrow it a bit. We don't have a good, general "how do I find digital tiles that suit my campaign?" question, so you could ask it separately to narrow this down yet more. (We *do* have a general ["how do I make digital tiles easily" question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/what-tools-are-available-to-create-custom-dungeon-maps) though, so take a look there too.)

Comment: (Ditto "how can I find/make virtual tokens that suit my campaign?": we don't have a good general one, so asking it yourself will narrow this down well.)

Comment: Regarding starmaps, we have this question: [Mapping software for 2D universe maps](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/mapping-software-for-2d-universe-maps)